# Purpose of Static Methods in ECMAScript 6 Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

What sort of issues with ES5 are static class methods in ES6 supposed to deal with?

The Babel documentation has the following example in [its section regarding ES6 classes](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#classes), though it does not actually state what this pattern accomplishes.

> Classes support prototype-based inheritance, super calls, instance and static methods and constructors

```
class SkinnedMesh extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor(geometry, materials) {
    super(geometry, materials);

    this.idMatrix = SkinnedMesh.defaultMatrix();
    this.bones = [];
    this.boneMatrices = [];
    //...
  }
  update(camera) {
    //...
    super.update();
  }
  static defaultMatrix() {
    return new THREE.Matrix4();
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I use the `static` keyword to indicate to the developer that *this method doesn't use information from the current* instance - similar to using underscore-prefixed names to indicate private properties - even though that may not necessarily be the case, it's a nice bit of self-commenting if used correctly

Comment: Very good example, thanks!

Comment: May I suggest to rename 'defaultMatrix' to 'createDefaultMatrix', because it is a very classical 'Factory Method' pattern (encapsulation of 'new' operator), and many agree to that convention.

Comment: @MartinMeeser As stated in the question, this code was pulled from Babel's documentation.

Answer (score 9):

If you compile ES6 code with Babel, and some class contains a static method, ES5-generated code will be just adding that static function to the constructor function.

So, this <strike>ES6</strike> ES2015 code:

```
class A {
   static doStuff() {}
}
```

...equals (in ES5):

```
function A() { }
A.doStuff = function() { };
```

***Why you need static functions?*** Well, transpiled code won't support statics at all, since even functions are objects and *static functions* are turned into *own properties of constructor function*.

Static functions or properties can be used to implement *factory pattern*:

```
class A {
   static create() {
      // Specific factory method code
   } 
}

var instance = A.create();
```

Anyway, static member usage is a very diffuse topic and it goes out of scope of an objective answer. It has a lot of use cases and these are universal to any programming language.

Comment: what is a `constructor function object functions`?

Comment: @1252748 An own property of constructor function. I'm going to edit.

Comment: Oh, that is a bit clearer, yes. But I am not the OP, I was just browsing the topic and stumbled upon your explanation. Thanks though :)

Comment: @1252748 You don't need to necessarily be the OP to suggest improvements :D

Answer (score 4):

Consider class that contains only static methods:

```
class MyNamespace {
  static foo() { ... }
  static bar() { foo(); }
}
```

It is quite convenient way of organizing code - put stuff in namespaces.

```
MyNamespace.foo();
MyNamespace.bar();
```

That's other than standard [static method use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) in other OOP languages.

Comment: Use object literals for namespaces. Not empty classes.

Comment: @Bergi Object literals have very inconvenient syntax for that purpose. 
You have to remember to put `,` and use anonymous functions, etc.

Comment: There's no reason to anonymous functions? You can just do `const MyNamespace = { foo() { … }, bar() { … } };`

Comment: @Bergi Commas are mandatory in object literals. So if you have large functions you will easily get lost in sequences like `{}}},},};` and the like... Anyway it is a matter of taste, both cases are conceptually the same.

Comment: @Bergi If not namespaces, what do you recommend to use static methods/properties for?

Comment: @1252748 Whenever you have functions that do not operate on an instance but definitely relate to the `class`, you can put them as static methods on the class (where the constructor acts as a namespace). However, this does not work the other way round: if you want to make a namespace but don't have instances or a constructor, do not use `class`.

Comment: Imo: If one get lost in `{}}},},};` it's time to re-factor. (And of course always use TABS for indentation).